# Python - an identical line of code using datetime fails in one file but not another

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x

I have the following lines of code in project A

```
#filename : mod_dates
#Handles date calculations etc

import datetime

class datecalcs:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__menuChoice = 0
        self.__datemonth = "not set"
        self.__effectivedate = ""
        self.__year = 0
        self.__month = 0
        return None

#
    def interestcouponpaydates(self,effectivedate,couponday):
        self.__effectivedate = effectivedate


        year, month, day = map(int,self.__effectivedate.split('-'))

        print(year)
        print(month)

        return self.__effectivedate
```

When I call them from another file with

```
import mod_dates
import datetime
import modcalinputs

datesclass = mod_dates.datecalcs()
calcInputs = modcalinputs.calcinputs()

#Get the coupon date
interestdateeffective = calcInputs.interestdateffective()
interestdatecoupon = calcInputs.interestdatecoupon()


x =     datesclass.interestcouponpaydates(interestdateeffective,interestdatecoupon)
print(x)
```

However this returns an error on the `x = datesclass...` line of

```
year, month, day = map(int,self.__effectivedate.split('-'))
```

raises:

```
> AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'split'
```

When I run from a similar project to the same line with the same syntax it works fine. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like something is assigning a datetime.date object to __effectivedate. You can't call split() on that:

```
>>> import date
>>> d = d = datetime.date(2012,3,12)
>>> d.split('-')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'split'
```

You can convert it to a string and split:

```
>>>str(d).split('-')
['2012', '03', '12']
```

Comment: That appears to have resolved the situation. Thanks Eric